# Read a file locally and use the vars remote in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I read a YAML file locally with the following playbook:

```
- name: Ensure the deploy_manifest var is defined and read deploy manifest
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: deploy_manifest is defined
        msg: |
          Error: Must provide providers config path. Fix: Add '-e deploy_manifest=/path/to/manifest' to the ansible-playbook command

    - name: Read deploy manifest
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ deploy_manifest }}"
        name: manifest
      register: manifest

    - debug:
        msg: "[{{ manifest.key }}]: {{ manifest.value }}"
      with_dict: "{{ manifest.ansible_facts }}"
```

and then in the same playbook YAML file I run:

```
- name: Deploy Backend services
  hosts: backend
  remote_user: ubuntu
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    env: "{{ env }}"
    services: "{{ manifest.ansible_facts }}"
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: services_backend
      when: backend | default(true) | bool
```

However it doesn't work because `debug` fails. It says that manifest is empty.

Which is the best way to read a YAML file or generally a configuration in a playbook and then have the variables passed in another playbook?

Comment: Please follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for your subsequent questions to make them at least minimally valuable for others.　・　You made a mistake in using a wrong variable name, yet your question is about: **the best way to read a YAML file or generally a configuration in a playbook and then have the variables passed in another playbook?** ー This is not what a user active on SO for over 6 years should be posting.

Comment: And the title "**Read a file locally and use the vars remote in Ansible** is an example of surrealism, not engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `debug` module doesn't say "*that manifest is empty*", it says the key `manifest.key` does not exist because it does not.

1. You registered a fact named `manifest` with:

   ```
   register: manifest
   ```
2. You try to refer to a key of the above `manifest` named `key` and another key (!) named `value`:

   ```
   msg: "[{{ manifest.key }}]: {{ manifest.value }}"
   ```

---

- Please read [Looping over Hashes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-hashes) chapter and acknowledge that (without using [loop control](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control)) you refer to the iterated variable **using `item`**.
- Please note that with `name: manifest` and `register: manifest` you read your vars file into `manifest.ansible_facts.manifest`.